# react-native-animated-pagination-dots: How can I place the dots below my view?

Tags: react-native

I'm using `ScalingDots` from [react-native-animated-pagiantion-dots](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-dots?activeTab=readme). Here is my code.

```
<View style={{ height: 200, width: 400, backgroundColor: "red" }} />
<ScalingDot 
    data={[0,1,2,3,4]}
    scrollX={scoll}
>
```

The looks like this.

[image]

How can I get the dots outside of the view which is placed above the ScalingDots (which is colored red)?

Comment: Please, try to be enough clear when asking a question. Define `red area` exactly.

Comment: I add more explanation. This is the view above the dots.

Comment: Please, take a look at [View](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view) before trying to do anything with it. Logically, if `ScalingDot` is assigned to preceding object(`View` in this case), it means you should add another `View`, right?

Comment: ScalingDot is not inside the View it is outside. <View /> is already the end tag.

Comment: You don't understand me, why don't you add an another `View`?

Comment: I think what @OrkhanAliyev means is that you need to wrap your ScalingDots-component inside another view and add the needed styling, e.g. some top margin.

Comment: @DavidScholz exactly!

Comment: Thank God! I'm glad that you made it! (Though I'm a `c++` programmer :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I was able to resolve this using this code.

```
<View style={{ height: 200, width: 400, backgroundColor: "red" }} />
<View style={{top: 20}}>
    <ScalingDot 
      data={[0,1,2,3,4]}
      scrollX={scoll}
    >
</View>
```